# I can't check if the user has subscribed to the channel, python aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='look_sub')
async def look(call: tp.CallbackQuery):
    user_channel_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='-100118155xxxx', user_id=call.from_user.id)
    if user_channel_status["status"] != 'left':
        await bot.send_message(
            call.from_user.id,
            'ok'
        )
    else:
        await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'not ok, subscribe please', reply_markup=keyboard_chat)
```

It should work, I found it online but it doesn't work

```
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: User not found
```

I tried to see if the id is being passed correctly, and yes, the user id is being passed correctly

Comment: Can you confirm that you are the administrator of that channel? Because get_chat_member method doesn't work unless you are the administrator of target channel.